# File fails to open with fstream C++ on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, file, fstream

Alright, so I could have sworn this worked in my program earlier, but now I'm being driven mad by `std::fstream`. I just want to open a file from command line arguments, ie.

`./main Program1.S`

should open the file Program1.S and scan it.

Here is how I set up a `open_file()` function in my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void open_file(std::fstream &ifp, std::string file_name) {
    ifp.open(file_name, std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    if(ifp.fail()) {
        std::cout << "File not found." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

void close_file(std::fstream &ofp) {
    if(ofp.is_open()) {
        ofp.close();
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "This file is not currently open" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::string in_name;
    in_name = argv[1];
    std::fstream ifp;
    open_file(ifp, in_name);
    // do some processing
    close_file(ifp);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I compile my program using (unfortunately I am required to use c++03): `g++ -g -std=c++03 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp -o main`

Compilation works and provides no errors, but when running the program using: `./main Program1.S`, it goes to `File not found` in `open_file()`. I even checked what was in `argv[1]` and it is definitely a file that is in the current working directory. Is there something wrong with the way I am doing this?

Comment: @KerrekSB I originally had that, but it gave me the same issue. Someone on stack overflow was upset that people were using `!ifp` which is how I found out about `ifp.fail()` in the first place.

Comment: Do `ls -l Program1.S`. And then try `$(pwd)/Program1.S`, too. Are you literally running the program the way you say, and not through some IDE? And print the working directory from within your program, too.

Comment: `ifp.open(file_name, std::ios::in | std::ios::out);` should not compile in C++03 as the overload that takes a `std::string` was not introduced until C++11.  see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bb98acaa0fe74d3

Comment: Please do not use fstream, be more specific and use ifstream or ofstream (you confuse yourself with ifp and ofp)

Comment: Try adding `<< std::strerror(errno)` in the error output, which displays the reason for the open failure (hopefully) (include `cerrno`, `cstring`)

Comment: @NathanOliver Spooky. Could the fact that OSX uses clang be doing this?

Comment: @Alex It shouldn't.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/905affddddb7daf9

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your file has been added to your project folder. Otherwise, you need to specify a file path within your computer ex. "/Mac HD/Documents/myfile". The program has no idea what to do with a external file name without its file path. Hope this helps.